# Как реализовать механику взаимодействия меча(ручного оружия) и твёрдого объекта?

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация, разработка-игр

Я хочу чтобы в 3d игре на unity при ударе мечом о объект(врага) анимация как бы останавливалась на моменте косания оружия и объекта, но при этом нужно чтобы оружие плавно переместилось в изачальное положение. Что-то на подобии kingdome come deliverance. У меня нет ни одной мысли как бы это можно было реализовать, может есть какие-то проуедурные анимации или это должно как-то просчитываться на физическом движке? Буду рад хотя бы наводке куда нужно копать.